# AutoMapper: What is the difference between PreserveReferences and MaxDepth?

Tags: c#, automapper, circular-reference

I'm a little bit confused. I can't find out the difference between `PreserveReferences` and `MaxDepth`.

Let's suppose we have the following DTOs and models.

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    public PersonEntity InnerPerson { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel
{
    public PersonModel InnerPerson { get; set; }
}
```

As written in the documentation:

> Previously, AutoMapper could handle circular references by keeping
>   track of what was mapped, and on every mapping, check a local
>   hashtable of source/destination objects to see if the item was already
>   mapped. It turns out this tracking is very expensive, and you need to
>   opt-in using PreserveReferences for circular maps to work.
>   Alternatively, you can configure MaxDepth.

My mappings:

```
cfg.CreateMap<PersonModel, PersonEntity>().MaxDepth(1);
cfg.CreateMap<PersonEntity, PersonModel>();
```

Program:

```
var personModel = new PersonModel();
personModel.InnerPerson = personModel;
var entity = Mapper.Map<PersonEntity>(personModel);
```

That is what I expect to get:

[image]

That is what I actually get:

[image]

I can use both of them (`PreserveReferences` and `MaxDepth`) for resolving circular references, but I don't see the difference. When I should use different number of depth in the `MaxDepth` method? So, could someone provide it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MaxDepth` doesn't consider object values at runtime. It simply stops mapping after the depth of the mapping tree reaches the configured value.

`PreserveReferences` doesn't help with `ProjectTo`, `MaxDepth` does. If somehow, with `Map`, you have a mapping tree that might overflow the stack, but objects instances are not duplicated, then `PreserveReferences` won't help, `MaxDepth` will.

`MaxDepth` is predictable, it stops at a hardcoded value, `PreserveReferences` stops only when an object instance is duplicated.

Comment: Could you provide a simple examples? It still has hard to understand it for me. Why `PreserveReferences` doesn't prevent stack overflowing? I successfully used it for my circular references.

Comment: It works because the object instances are duplicated, it won't work otherwise. MaxDepth will work regardless.

Comment: Seems like I got it. If I will have the different instance of the `PersonEntity` in the `InnerPerson` property each time it will cause stack overflow exception and `PreserveReferences` won't help me. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Lucian Bargaoanu for the answer. I just want to add a simple example of `MaxDepth`.

I recently changed my DTOs and models.

```
public class SelfEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number;
    public SelfEntity InnerSelfEntity { get; set; }
}

public class SelfModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number;
    public SelfModel InnerSelfModel { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SelfModel, SelfEntity>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Id.ToString()))
.MaxDepth(3);
```

Program:

```
SelfModel firstSelfModel = new SelfModel();
SelfModel prev = firstSelfModel;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   SelfModel newModel = new SelfModel
   {
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Name = "Test name" + i.ToString(),
      Number = i
   };

   prev.InnerFirstSelf = newModel;
   prev = newModel;
}

var entity = Mapper.Map<FirstSelfEntity>(firstSelfModel);
```

Starts from the 3-th level of depth we will get `null` for the `InnerSelfModel`.

> PreserveReferences doesn't help with ProjectTo, MaxDepth does. If
>   somehow, with Map, you have a mapping tree that might overflow the
>   stack, but objects instances are not duplicated, then
>   PreserveReferences won't help, MaxDepth will.